# Chrome Extension: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Recently, it is reported that the context menu of my app is vanished. If you remove the app and reinstall it, it works. But the vanishment happens again.

I found an error. I'm not sure if the error causes the vanishment of the context menu. But I'd like to fix this matter, because all I found is this.

This app shows texts you select in a page. When you select texts in an ordinaly page and click browser action button, it works without error. But if you try it on Google Docs, you will get error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist".

I'm afraid I don't know what to do with this. And I might have two problems. It'll be great help if you could give me some advice.

[manifest.js]

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Chrome Extension",
    "short_name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "This is a test.",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["googleDocsUtil.js", "content_scripts.js"]
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "48.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Test Chrome Extension"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "background",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

[background.js]

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    type: 'normal',
    id: 'testchromeextension',
    title: 'Test Chrome Extension',
    contexts:['selection']
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info,tab){
    if( info.menuItemId == 'testchromeextension' ){
        var selectedText = info.selectionText.replace(/ /g, "\n");
        doSomething(selectedText);
    }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response) {
            doSomething(response.data);
        });
    });
});

function doSomething(selectedText) {
    console.log(selectedText);
}
```

[content_scripts.js]

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getSelection") {
        var post_val = window.getSelection().toString();
        if ( !post_val ) {
            var googleDocument = googleDocsUtil.getGoogleDocument();
            post_val = googleDocument.selectedText;
        }
        sendResponse({data: post_val});
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like google docs may be protected in some corporate networks - check out chrome://policy

Comment: Thank you! I will.

Comment: I checked chrome://policy, but there is no sign about error..

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained to you more clearly. There is no restricted URLs. I only see Chrome policies "MaxInvalidationFetchDelay". [capture](https://gyazo.com/808175a1f41e97fe41e1ab78884ebc7f) This is written in Japanese.

Comment: Another guess: the offline docs extension is installed and it interferes in some way.

Comment: I offed all extensions except my app and refresh every page. But I still have error..

Comment: 1) Theoretically this could be a bug in Chrome - see if an older portable Chrome installer is fine (like v60 or even older). 2) Remove chrome.tabs.query in browserAction.onClicked and use `tab.id` directly.

Comment: I removed `chrome.tabs.query` and modified code to `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(193, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response) {`. I still have error.

Comment: I tried same app with Windows, it works! (I usually try it on Mac) In addition to it, I found it works on another Google Document. The difference of two documents is user who create a document. One with error is a user of G Suite, the other is private account.

Comment: Again, I found something new. I apologize that it worked, if I opened the Google Document on a new tab. It didn't work if I refresh the browser several times.. I'm sorry for confusing you. But I still have a problem that context menu is vanished. I think this question title is not suitable for my problem any more. I'll close this question and ask again with new question. 

@wOxxOm Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 11):

I believe this error is caused when you update the local version of an extension and then try to use the extension with its old/not-updated source code.

The fix: after you reload your local extension at `chrome://extensions/`, make sure you **refresh the page you're using the extension on**. You should no longer see the error.

Comment: Very sample and easy, that was actually my problem, thank you :)

Comment: is this documented anywhere?